# Start app panel size different from screen size

Tags: 8.1

I am using a Lumia 635 with WinPhone 8.1. For some unknown reasons, the start app panel could not fit into my screen size. I would like to have my full size app panel back, but I don't know how to make it. The attachment is a screen shot of my current app panel and I will appreciate any help and suggestion.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you have activated the third start screen column "show more tiles" in settings -> start + theme. You can either fill that extra column with apps or deactivate that setting.

Comment: Thanks for your hint, Thomas. I found the option in settings -> start+theme -> show more tiles, and put it off. Now my full screen panel is back :)

Comment: I updated my answer with the correct setting names, wasn't quite sure as my phone is currently running a different language ;-)